# Changing resolution LogicalDpiChanged event not firing in Windows 8 Metro application

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, resolution

I am implementing C# Metro application in this app, and am implementing this event

```
DisplayProperties.LogicalDpiChanged += DisplayProperties_LogicalDpiChanged;
```

statically changing simulator resolution is not firing.

Comment: It works in a simple test application I just created. It fires when I changed the DPI of the simulator. Where did you attach it?

Comment: I am using vs2011 DPI changing the run time some times firing some times not firing.

Comment: If you've hooked the event correctly, it would seem that it may be a bug in the framework or Windows. Are you using the RTM versions of Windows 8 and the .NET Framework?

Comment: Hi i am using consumer preview vs2011 and .net4.5

Comment: That's an awfully old version of Windows 8 and .NET 4.5. I would grab the trial of the RTM and try it there.